# How is Magnesium Ethoxide appropriately prepared, stored and used to dry ethanol?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, alcohols, safety

I found many procedures vaguely describing the preparation of magnesium ethoxide from elemental magnesium in excess dry ethanol in the presence of I2 as activator (in absence of air), I also know that detailed procedures exist in publications I cannot access.

What is the smallest I2 to Mg ratio I can use without significantly affecting the speed of the reaction (assuming I'm fine to let it sit a few hours at max 40C)?

Is it appropriate to store it under 5x excess ethanol, itself under argon, in a glass bottle at 5-25C?

When used to dry 90-95% ethanol, is it appropriate to add only say 110% its molar counterpart in water content, and just stirr it an hour at ambient temperature? Given that after filtration traces will be left dissolved in the dried ethanol, can it still be safely distilled at atmospheric pressure knowing there will be a little bit of air in contact with the ethanol? (Magnesium Ethanoate, alone, having a flash point of 43C)

Comment: Generally you would use magnesium metal rather than magnesium ethoxide to dry ethanol. See [this video from NurdRage on methanol drying](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NMfs3e9OdZQ), though it should be closely analogous for ethanol. Ultimately, molecular sieves are better, though 90-95% ethanol is a rather wet starting point.

Comment: Thank you for your response and for the video. In the video this man does dry the alcohol with magnesium methoxide (formed in situ). He mentions himself dropping iodine to accelerate the process, which he carries out under heating with methanol (which is much more reactive than ethanol). All my questions stand.

Comment: This video on solvent drying includes EtOH at about 7.45  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RawVXnMSyXc&t=103s

Comment: @Waylander: Thank you for the video. I had read the paper that he took the table from but I would like to use magnesium ethoxide because it's fairly fast acting, efficient, and doesn't require me to buy anything I don't already have at hand.

Comment: @Hans  I have never made and stored Mg ethoxide so cannot offer any advice.

Answer (score 3):

To dry absolute ethanol [not 95 -99.5%] magnesium ethoxide is generated in situ by adding a small amount of dry Mg turnings, the same quality used to make a Grignard reaction, to the ethanol in a flask with stirrer and condenser. The reaction usually starts by the addition of a tiny iodine crystal that is allowed to settle on a chip, a second crystal is allowable. I recommend that this process be practiced on small amounts of alcohol and Mg to make sure the alcohol is dry enough to start and the magnesium is not too heavily coated with oxide. In general take all the precautions one takes in running a Grignard reaction.  This procedure also works for drying iso-propanol and, if I remember correctly, for tertiary butanol. I never tried it for methanol.  If the starting ethanol is the 95% azeotrope preliminary drying with calcium oxide is necessary. I found that the high quality commercial grade of absolute alcohol gave superior results and uv analysis showed no detectable benzene. Today solvents are of higher quality.

Comment: What is the smallest I2 to Mg ratio I can use without significantly affecting the speed of the reaction (assuming I'm fine to let it sit a few hours at max 40C)? Is it ok to use just 1% as much I2 as Mg if using 99.0% Ethanol?

Comment: Given that after filtration traces of magnesium ethanoate will be left dissolved in the dried ethanol, can it still be safely distilled at atmospheric pressure knowing there will be a little bit of air in contact with the ethanol? (Magnesium Ethanoate, alone, having a flash point of 43C)